# I can not save entity (Spring Boot Application)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity(name = "cities")
public class City {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(length = 256, unique = true, nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(length = 4, nullable = false, unique = true)
private String code;

//    @OneToMany(mappedBy="city")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
private List<ParkingFacility> parkingFacilities = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="city")
private List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

```
@Entity(name = "parking_facilities")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class ParkingFacility {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
protected Integer id;

@Column(length = 256, unique = true, nullable = false)
protected String name;


protected Integer capacity = 0;

@Column(name = "available_capacity")
protected  Integer availableCapacity = 0;

//    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
//    @JoinColumn(name="city_id", nullable=false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
protected City city;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="parkingFacility")
private List<Vehicle> vehicles;
```

---

```
public class ParkingFacilityDto {

protected Integer id;
@NotBlank @Length(max = 256)
protected String name;
@Min(0)
protected Integer capacity;
@Min(0)
protected Integer availableCapacity;
@NotBlank @Length(max = 256)
protected String city;
```

---

```
public class ParkingFacilityMapper {



public static ParkingFacility toFacility(ParkingFacilityDto facilityDto) {

    return ParkingFacility.builder()
            .name(facilityDto.getName())
            .capacity(facilityDto.getCapacity())
            .availableCapacity(facilityDto.getAvailableCapacity())
            .city(new City(InputFormatter.formatCityName(facilityDto.getCity())))
            .build();

}
```

}

I am trying to save a Parking Facility for a given city, but I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient 
instance - save the transient instance before flushing : 
com.goosfraba.city_parking.parking_facilities.model.ParkingFacility.city -> 
com.goosfraba.city_parking.cities.model.City; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object 
references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : 
com.goosfraba.city_parking.parking_facilities.model.ParkingFacility.city -> com.goosfraba.city_parking.cities.model.City",
```

I have seen many people recommending to use CascadeType.All on similar questions asked on StackOverflow, but as you can see I am already using it, and still get this error.

Please help me as I do not know what to from here

Answer (score 0):

Add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
protected City city
```

this will solve your problem.

Comment: And I still have to keep cascade on OneToMany?

Comment: It does not work as I want to, because now it tries to create a new City entity, but I want to use the ones that already exist